# Can't remove gcc on armhf

Tags: apt, gcc, arm

When I am trying to remove `gcc-4.9`, it is trying to remove all my root file system.

```
apt-get purge gcc-4.9-base
```

Returns:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:


adduser* apt* apt-utils* base-files* base-passwd* bash* bsdmainutils*
  bsdutils* busybox* busybox-initramfs* coreutils* cpio* dash* dbus* debconf*
  debconf-i18n* debianutils* deborphan* devmem2* diffutils* dmsetup* dpkg*
  e2fslibs* e2fsprogs* file* findutils* gcc-4.9-base* gnupg* gpgv* grep* gzip*
  hostname* ifupdown* initramfs-tools* initramfs-tools-bin* initscripts*
  insserv* iproute2* iputils-ping* isc-dhcp-client* isc-dhcp-common*
  keyboard-configuration* kmod* libacl1* libapparmor1* libapt-inst1.5*
  libapt-pkg4.12* libattr1* libaudit1* libblkid1* libbz2-1.0* libc-bin* libc6*
  libcap2* libcap2-bin* libcgmanager0* libcomerr2* libdb5.3* libdbus-1-3*
  libdebconfclient0* libdevmapper1.02.1* libdrm2* libexpat1* libffi6*
  libfribidi0* libgcc1* libgcrypt11* libgnutls-openssl27* libgnutls26*
  libgpg-error0* libiw30* libjson-c2* libjson0* libkmod2*
  liblocale-gettext-perl* liblockfile-bin* liblockfile1* liblzma5* libmagic1*
  libmount1* libncurses5* libncursesw5* libnewt0.52* libnih-dbus1* libnih1*
  libnl-3-200* libnl-genl-3-200* libp11-kit0* libpam-cap* libpam-modules*
  libpam-modules-bin* libpam-runtime* libpam0g* libpcre3* libpcsclite1*
  libpipeline1* libplymouth2* libpng12-0* libpopt0* libprocps3* libreadline5*
  libreadline6* libselinux1* libsemanage1* libsepol1* libslang2* libss2*
  libssl1.0.0* libstdc++6* libsystemd-login0* libtasn1-6*
  libtext-charwidth-perl* libtext-iconv-perl* libtext-wrapi18n-perl*
  libtinfo5* libudev1* libusb-0.1-4* libusb-1.0-0* libustr-1.0-1* libuuid1*
  locales* lockfile-progs* login* lshw* makedev* mawk* module-init-tools*
  mount* mountall* multiarch-support* nano* ncurses-bin* net-tools* ntpdate*
  passwd* perl-base* plymouth* procps* rcn-ee-archive-keyring*
  readline-common* resolvconf* sed* sysv-rc* sysvinit-utils* tar* tzdata* ucf*
  udev* upstart* usb-modeswitch* usbutils* util-linux* whiptail*
  wireless-tools* wpasupplicant* zlib1g*
```

Why?

What if I remove it by force and check no dependencies? Because I don't want `gcc` in my embedded device. Takes much space and a compiler on an embedded device makes no sense except if it is a development device.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. `gcc-4.9-base` is a dependency of `libstdc++6` (the shared library files for the C++ standard library), and both are part of `ubuntu-minimal`. `gcc-X.Y-base` packages do not contain compiler frontends, so if you don't want a `gcc` binary in your embedded system, just remove the corresponding `gcc-X.Y` package (`gcc-4.9`, for example).

Comment: Hmmm, so there is a misunderstanding by me. Thanks for your answer (: